# QGIS - Shape missing when exporting as svg

Tags: qgis, export, svg

I am using QGIS to export some maps, and when I export quite complex layers, it looks like some shapes are missing.

Here is the map I want to export (from QGIS)
[image]

And here is what I get when I export

[image]

I've circled some of the differences between the two maps. I have tried exporting as SVG and PDF to open it with Illustrator, but I've got the same result every time.

I've also tried to simplify the layer before exporting and exporting each colour individually, but without any success so far...

Comment: Have you checked for geometry errors? Also, did you try to open it with something other than Illustrator?

Comment: @CezarB, Thank you for your comment. I checked and there are no errors. I haven't tried anything else than Illustrator but I'm sure what else to use as this is how I build my maps. Subdividing the layer worked, but I'm keen to see if there is another way of fixing this.

Comment: The image looks like an animal with glasses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had this issue in the past.
The solution was to first **subdivide** the layer using the **[Subdivide Tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#subdivide)**.
The resultant subdivided layer exported with no loss.
[image: Fig. 25.94 Subdivide]

My understanding is that it is related to the size and complexity of the feature (multipart, donut holes etc).
*(There will be more 'edges' to the layer which might or might not be an issue depending on how the layer is styled)*

Comment: I've just tried and it worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help !